# Can a Javascript - WebGL proof of work system prevent website spam?

Tags: javascript, spam, threat-mitigation, captcha

Is it a good idea to come up with a Javascript-based Proof of Work system to reduce spam on forums, and other websites?

This idea would be similar to HashCash, but the computation would be based on the hash of the contents to be submitted + a seed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript's performance on computationally intensive tasks is... less than desirable. Which is why you talk of WebGL, but you are actually thinking of [WebCL](http://www.khronos.org/webcl/), an upcoming technology to give access to general computing features of GPU to Javascript code in Web browsers (à la [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)).

I see three main issues with such a proposal:

- There is a large disparity in available computing power in client systems, especially for GPU. It will be hard to find an acceptable compromise between people with gaming PC and people with low-power tablets.
- There is no WebGL, let alone WebCL, in Internet Explorer.
- Proofs of work are good to deter spammers which are short on CPU. But spammers are not really short on CPU; any competent enough spammer will use a [botnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet) with thousands of available processors.

Comment: To counter the CPU and Javascript less than perfect match, maybe a more memory-bound Proof of Work can help? ....Even though that it is clear that a botnet is also resourceful in memory memory....

Comment: true, a botnet can ax a proof of work quite a bit, but it cant completely obliterate it. because without proof of work, the only burden is bandwidth, but with proof of work, one cant just send out millions of requests in that much of a short time period. also a botnet victim should notice when the computer is really going slow because of the PoW calculations.

Comment: To add to humanityANDpeace's comment, a real-life memory-bound algorithm was made for this exact purpose. It is known as Equihash, and it was made by the same inventor of Argon2, the winner of the 2015 PHC. It forces the prover to use a certain amount of memory that is tweakable by changing the n and k parameters--but this is still a very slow task. And forcing Javascript to execute it would be a bad idea. Instead, the website developer should translate the C++ Equihash source code to WebAssembly. (https://github.com/khovratovich/equihash)